# How to add a custom field in TFS Express?

Tags: tfs

I'm working on a project which will need to use some custom fields in TFS. I'm working on this using a TFS Express installed on my local machine.

But I could not figure out how to add custom fields to the TFS Express. The doc I could find is for VSTS.

Can we add custom fields in TFS Express? How?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using TFS Express over VSTS? It's not going to be a sustainable, realistic multi-user solution if you have it installed on your development machine, and if you're only using it for yourself, then VSTS is free for up to 5 users.

Comment: it is simply because what I'm doing is a prototype for an existing system which uses TFS, and I could not change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to modify your process template XML. It's way too big a topic to go into in any detail here, so consult [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/process-templates/customize-process?view=vsts). What you're looking for is the "on-premises XML" model.

The basic step-by-step is:

- Export your work item with `witadmin`
- Modify the XML with your editor of choice
- Import the work item with `witadmin`

Another option is to use the [Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) plugin for Visual Studio.

However, please see my comment regarding your choice to install TFS Express over using VSTS. A workstation is not a realistic TFS environment.

Comment: I added that successfully, but have a question which will post in another post. thanks.

Comment: the new question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375644/add-custom-column-to-ui-in-tfs , thanks